# Firestore rules for creating a user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase and trying to use firebase authentication, along with firestore database. It looks like all the security lies in rules we set, however I want to know the following:

1. Is it possible to apply rules based on user authentication without using firebase authentication system ?
2. How can I make sure that the users are only created through my application ? Would anyone with my firebase credentials (Which are easily exposed in browser) be able to add users to the database ? I understand that there is no domain based locking on firestore, but is user creation atleast domain based ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication is the only way to populate the `request.auth` variable in security rules. So if you want to secure based on a user, you'll need to create that user in Firebase Authentication.

You can however:

- Use anonymous authentication to generate a UID for users, without requiring them to enter credentials.
- If you have an existing sign-in system, you can hook that up to Firebase Authentication as a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth). This would then make your user details available in `request.auth` in the security rules.

To lock access to your Firestore database down to users from a specific domain, you'd use something like this in your security rules:

```
request.auth.token.email_verified && 
  request.auth.token.email.matches(".*@google.com")
```

So this only allows access once a user has verified the email address in their profile, and if that email address is from he given domain.